# Websocket Authentication and Authorization in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, websocket

I've been struggling a lot to properly implement Stomp (websocket) **Authentication** and **Authorization** with Spring-Security. *For posterity i'll answer my own question to provide a guide.*

#### The Problem

Spring WebSocket documentation (for Authentication) looks unclear ATM (IMHO). And i couldn't understand how to properly handle **Authentication** and **Authorization**.

#### What i want

- Authenticate users with login/password.
- Prevent anonymous users to CONNECT though WebSocket.
- Add authorization layer (user, admin, ...).
- Having `Principal` available in controllers.

#### What i don't want

- Authenticate on HTTP negotiation endpoints (since most of JavaScript libraries don't sends authentication headers along with the HTTP negotiation call).

Comment: Great write-up. Is it a worse approach, to actually defer authentication even further, to the handling of the first SEND frame? as opposed to the CONNECT frame. I am not yet clear on any benefits it might yield, but is it perhaps a no-no, compared to the way you describe in the answer?

Comment: ...first SEND or SUBSCRIBE, in fact

Comment: IMHO it's better to do it on CONNECT (and STOMP to support v1.2), because it's a common entrypoint instead of SEND, SUBSCRIBE, BEGIN, or any other Frame that may be introduce in future RFC

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30887788/json-web-token-jwt-with-spring-based-sockjs-stomp-web-socket

Answer (score 143, accepted):

As stated above the documentation looks unclear (IMHO), until Spring provide some clear documentation, here is a boilerplate to save you from spending two days trying to understand what the security chain is doing.

A really nice attempt was made by [Rob-Leggett](https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/angular_websockets_security) but, he was [forking some Springs class](https://github.com/Rob-Leggett/angular_websockets_security/tree/master/security/src/main/java/au/com/example/security/spring/security/config) and I don't feel comfortable doing so.

Things to know before you start:

- *Security chain* and *Security config* for **http** and **WebSocket** are completely independent.
- Spring `AuthenticationProvider` take not part at all in Websocket authentication.
- The authentication won't happen on HTTP negotiation endpoint in our case, because none of the JavaScripts STOMP (websocket) libraries I know sends the necessary authentication headers along with the HTTP request.
- Once set on CONNECT request, the *user* (`simpUser`) will be stored in the websocket session and no more authentication will be required on further messages.

#### Maven deps

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

#### WebSocket configuration

The below config register a simple message broker (a simple endpoint that we will later protect).

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(final MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // These are endpoints the client can subscribes to.
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/queue/topic");
        // Message received with one of those below destinationPrefixes will be automatically router to controllers @MessageMapping
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // Handshake endpoint
        registry.addEndpoint("stomp"); // If you want to you can chain setAllowedOrigins("*")
    }
}
```

#### Spring security config

Since the Stomp protocol rely on a first HTTP Request, we'll need to authorize HTTP call to our stomp handshake endpoint.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // This is not for websocket authorization, and this should most likely not be altered.
        http
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/stomp").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}
```

Then we'll create a service responsible for authenticating users.

```
@Component
public class WebSocketAuthenticatorService {
    // This method MUST return a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken instance, the spring security chain is testing it with 'instanceof' later on. So don't use a subclass of it or any other class
    public UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthenticatedOrFail(final String  username, final String password) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (username == null || username.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Username was null or empty.");
        }
        if (password == null || password.trim().isEmpty()) {
            throw new AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException("Password was null or empty.");
        }
        // Add your own logic for retrieving user in fetchUserFromDb()
        if (fetchUserFromDb(username, password) == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad credentials for user " + username);
        }

        // null credentials, we do not pass the password along
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                username,
                null,
                Collections.singleton((GrantedAuthority) () -> "USER") // MUST provide at least one role
        );
    }
}
```

Note that: `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` **MUST** have at least one GrantedAuthority, if you use another constructor, Spring will auto-set `isAuthenticated = false`.

Almost there, now we need to create an Interceptor that will set the `simpUser` header or throw `AuthenticationException` on CONNECT messages.

```
@Component
public class AuthChannelInterceptorAdapter extends ChannelInterceptor {
    private static final String USERNAME_HEADER = "login";
    private static final String PASSWORD_HEADER = "passcode";
    private final WebSocketAuthenticatorService webSocketAuthenticatorService;

    @Inject
    public AuthChannelInterceptorAdapter(final WebSocketAuthenticatorService webSocketAuthenticatorService) {
        this.webSocketAuthenticatorService = webSocketAuthenticatorService;
    }

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) throws AuthenticationException {
        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);

        if (StompCommand.CONNECT == accessor.getCommand()) {
            final String username = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(USERNAME_HEADER);
            final String password = accessor.getFirstNativeHeader(PASSWORD_HEADER);

            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = webSocketAuthenticatorService.getAuthenticatedOrFail(username, password);

            accessor.setUser(user);
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

Note that: `preSend()` **MUST** return a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, another element in the spring security chain test this.
Note that: If your `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` was built without passing `GrantedAuthority`, the authentication will fail, because the constructor without granted authorities auto set `authenticated = false` **THIS IS AN IMPORTANT DETAIL which is not documented in spring-security**.

Finally create two more class to handle respectively Authorization and Authentication.

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 99)
public class WebSocketAuthenticationSecurityConfig extends  WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Inject
    private AuthChannelInterceptorAdapter authChannelInterceptorAdapter;
    
    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(final StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // Endpoints are already registered on WebSocketConfig, no need to add more.
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(final ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.setInterceptors(authChannelInterceptorAdapter);
    }

}
```

Note that: The `@Order` is **CRUCIAL** don't forget it, it allows our interceptor to be registered first in the security chain.

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketAuthorizationSecurityConfig extends AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    protected void configureInbound(final MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
        // You can customize your authorization mapping here.
        messages.anyMessage().authenticated();
    }

    // TODO: For test purpose (and simplicity) i disabled CSRF, but you should re-enable this and provide a CRSF endpoint.
    @Override
    protected boolean sameOriginDisabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't quite understand - what's wrong with the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html) on this? Why aren't you using `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`? As it stands you have no CSRF. Also, I sincerely hope your passwords are stored hashed in the database...

Comment: i do use `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` (take a look at the last code block) but this class is just for Authorization, you just can't register a Interceptor before the security check and thus fill your `simpUser`. To register the interceptor before the security check you have to use `AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer `with a super high `@Order`. Plus the Interceptor must fill the `simpUser` with a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` and nothing else, which is not documented at all.

Comment: *As it stands you have no CSRF. Also, I sincerely hope your passwords are stored hashed in the database*. Woops, i disabled CSRF for test purpose and forgot to remove this line. - I personaly don't use database, there is only one user allowed to connect, and the password is defined at runtime.

Comment: Quoting from the [Spring Security guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html) "_More concretely, to ensure a user has authenticated to your WebSocket application, all that is necessary is to ensure that you setup Spring Security to authenticate your HTTP based web application._" So, the point is, that you authenticate access to the `http` endpoint using standard Spring Security methods, then you verify CSRF on `CONNECT` and use role based security on configured STOMP destinations. I am still unsure of the use case for the above.

Comment: The fact is that none of the javascrip STOMP libraries are passing authentication headers along with the HTTP handshake call. And Spring has chosen to allow users to authenticate only though HTTP. But we cant blame them for that, the WebSocket RFC is unclear and very permissive on this subject: *This protocol doesn't prescribe any particular way that servers can authenticate clients during the WebSocket handshake.*

Comment: But if only an authenticated user can _access_ the websocket endpoint then reauthenticating them on `CONNECT` is a little pointless. No?

Comment: None of JavaScript stomp library send authentication headers along with http handshake. So you can't restrict access to the http negociation endpoint. You have to authenticate your users on CONNECT. Of course if you use a spring client you won't need all of this overwelmed stuff. The point of this boilerplate is to provide an example that use Spring backend for JavaScript stomp clients.

Comment: But to _connect_ to the websocket, you need access to the URL. _That_ is where the Spring Security authentication kicks in. Then the role based authorisation ensures that the authenticated user can only subscribe to the appropriate locations. I really don't see what adding credentials to `CONNECT` adds, as that user is _already authenticated_ during access to the URL.

Comment: Spring described method state that : *You should provide sufficient information (login password or whatever) while accessing the HTTP necotiation endpoint (handshake endpoint) to allow Spring to authenticate you through the Spring-Security chain*. But none of the javaScript STOMP libraries do send these information along with the HTTP negiciation call. These headers are sent with `CONNECT` message in `nativeHeaders: { login: xxxx, passcode: xxxx}`. Therefore if no informations are sent on HTTP call, you can't authenticate at this point.

Comment: I want to implement machine to backend web socket authentication and authorization, there are no user Principle, then how can I proceed?

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't undestand your question

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I'm getting `message:Failed to send message to ExecutorSubscribableChannel[clientInboundChannel]; nested exception is org.springframework.security.web.csrf.MissingCsrfTokenException\c Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.
content-length:0`. Only changes I made are:
`1.)`  removed `sameOriginDisabled`
`2.)` left `Collections.singleton((GrantedAuthority) () -> "USER"));` but I'm not quite sure what it supposed to do. I have different roles for users if this is it. F.e. I defined `USERS_READ`, `USERS_EDIT` etc., should I change it ?

Comment: If you enable `sameOriginDisabled` you have to obtain a CSRF token from the server in order to init a connection. This is kind of a pain in the ass since most of the JS libraries don't send http headers along with the HTTP request anyway... If i were you i would just re-disable the CSRF. BUT be sure that you are aware of the risks, run some google search about CSRF if you are not familiar with. Also i believe that CSRF implies sessions, so you should most likely remove `.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)`.

Comment: AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer has been deprecated.

Comment: You can use [WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/socket/config/annotation/WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.html) instead.

Comment: I too needed this, I did as mentioned, but if CONNECT call throws exception, SUBSCRIBE & SEND are working fine. I thought if CONNECT throws exception, other frames won't work. Can you correct me if I am wrong?. I'm passing headers in all the frames and I'm authenticating now. But I feel this seems wrong.

Comment: Yep, it definely seems wrong, i'll need to take a look at that. Unfortunately i don't have much times these days. I'll get back to you as soon i had enought time to check if out

Comment: @Manoj can you describe how you succed in sending other frame with an error on CONNECT ? Or maybe a link to your client project code?

Comment: sorry, I couldn't replicate it now. If I come across again, I will post the code.

Comment: getAuthenticatedOrFail is failing because, after sending the request, the password change itself to "PROTECTED" and the pass comparasion fails. If I change the header name from "passcode" to "pass" (or something else) everything works thine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i do'nt think tha tthe password is changinf from something to PROTECTED. On the other hand, most of the time spring's developper override the `.toString()` methods of objects and show PROTECTED instead of the password. I think that this is what you are talking about. If you add a breakpoint on the line `fetchUserFromDb(username, password)` what do you see as a password?

Comment: Then I really misunderstand something because I think this documentation clearly say that the common security settings are shared amongst the http and the websocket accesses: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-authentication

Comment: Yep `WebSockets reuse the same authentication information that is found in the HTTP request when the WebSocket connection was made`. That is true, Websockets (so do stomp) rely on a first HTTP negotiation call, and spring expects that the authentication will take place here. But there is not a single stomp JS libs that forwards the credentials during this negotiation call. because of that you need to authenticate after the negotioation. And thus use the websocket to authenticate. That's why i sais that the two chains are decoupled.

Comment: Can you please share `fetchUserFromDb(username, password)` method code. Because I am saving my password in DB in hashes. I don't know how to match the password. Also in my application i want to notify other users if an user logout from app. But i found once the `HttpSession` expires i am not able to send messages. So how can i do it. Thanks.

Comment: @Nazim For the first point it's already well explain all over the internet, i'll let you google about that. For the second point i'm sorry but i have no idea

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond I am using Redis for session. I tried debugging the `StompHeaderAccessor` and i got `null` for both `username` and `password` header. I am getting `x-auth-token` in header.Now can you please tell me how to verify the user ? Thanks.

Comment: I could not be more agree that it is like "spending two days trying to understand"

Comment: Still to this day, your post is the ONLY thing that works. Spring boot documentation is still lacking clear instructions. Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I don't wanna use Stomp i just used this as websocket handler: registry.addHandler(activeUsersWebSocketHandler, "/active-users") but if i use this endpoint in the permitAll it will ignore and filter anyway, any help please

Answer (score 4):

for java client side use this tested example:

```
StompHeaders connectHeaders = new StompHeaders();
connectHeaders.add("login", "test1");
connectHeaders.add("passcode", "test");
stompClient.connect(WS_HOST_PORT, new WebSocketHttpHeaders(), connectHeaders, new MySessionHandler());
```

Comment: This will work with stomp.js too. But these are *STOMP* headers (on the CONNECT frame). The original issue is that stomp.js won't set *HTTP* websocket-handshake headers that'd be used by Spring Security to automatically authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

Going with spring authentication is a pain. You can do it in a simple way. Create a web Filter and read the Authorization token by yourself, then perform the authentication.

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletRequest instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
            String authorization = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            if (/*Your condition here*/) {
                // logged
                filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            } else {
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
                response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
                response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE);
                response.getWriter().write("{\"message\": "\Bad login\"}");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Then in your configuration define the filter using the spring mechanism:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CustomAuthenticationFilter> securityFilter(
            CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter){
        FilterRegistrationBean<CustomAuthenticationFilter> registrationBean
                = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();

        registrationBean.setFilter(customAuthenticationFilter);
        registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree that spring security is a long way, but doing so you loose all the convenience brought by spring-security (being able to get the User from anywhere in the request context, test mocking, ...)

Comment: There is no convenience in complexity. In my approach you still can inject your service and check username and password. For example you can inject WebSocketAuthenticatorService  and do the check by splitting Authorization and get the username pass if this is Basic AUTH. There is no right or wrong solution here as long as it works, I prefer this as it is more elegant for me. Others might prefer other.

Answer (score 1):

#### Spring 3 and disabled CSRF protection

It also can be done with `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` and **disabled** csrf protection (in case if you don't need it). And in that case, you configuration will be quite simple.

Here is my example. It's on Kotlin, but I think it's still easy to get the idea.

Security configuration:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorizationManager
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.socket.EnableWebSocketSecurity
import org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager


@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun messageAuthorizationManager(messages: MessageMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager.Builder): AuthorizationManager<Message<*>> {
        messages.nullDestMatcher().authenticated()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/app/notifications").permitAll()
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/queue/tasks/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_tasks.read")
            .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        return messages.build()
    }

}
```

Custom CSRF interceptor:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.messaging.Message
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel
import org.springframework.messaging.support.ChannelInterceptor
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component("csrfChannelInterceptor")
class CustomCsrfChannelInterceptor : ChannelInterceptor {

    override fun preSend(message: Message<*>, channel: MessageChannel): Message<*>? {
        return message;
    }

}
```

And that's it. You can configure authorization/authentication politics in the config, using all the advantages of `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` and you don't have to deal with the CSRF protection if you don't need it. Unfortunately, at present, there is no easier way to disable the protection.

Link to the comprehensive Spring's guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/websocket.html#websocket-authorization

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/NaikSoftware/StompProtocolAndroid) Stomp Client library for Android then you actually can add Http headers to initial handshake request.

Here is an example:

```
Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
headers.put("Authorization", "Your auth token");
    
StompClient stompClient = Stomp.over(Stomp.ConnectionProvider.OKHTTP, 
        "ws://example.com/api/websocket", headers);
```