# How to use STOMP with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, spring-security, jwt, stomp

```
 let client = Stomp.client("ws://192.168.181.77:3001/ws");
    client.connect(
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization:
            "Bearer TOKEN",
        },
      },
      () => {
        console.log("client ok");
      },
      () => {
        console.log("client not ok");
      }
    );
```

I am Trying to connect to the Stomp Broker using stompjs library. but i am unable to send the auth headers there for i get the 401 respond. how to send my token with the connect request therefore I won't get this 401 error

I used wireshark to investigate about the problem and I found out that the header is not present in the request eventhough I am setting it as a header

Answer (score 0):

The headers which you are passing part of stompClient#connect will be passed as the header of CONNECT stomp frame sent via the websocket, and not as the request header.

As per [spring websocket site](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket/stomp/authentication-token-based.html),

> In practice, however, browser clients can use only standard authentication headers (that is, basic HTTP authentication) or cookies and cannot (for example) provide custom headers.

and also from [Spring site's Introduction to WebSocket](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/websocket.html#introduction-to-websocket)

> A WebSocket interaction begins with an HTTP request that uses the HTTP Upgrade header to upgrade or, in this case, to switch to the WebSocket protocol.

To allow the initial HTTP negotiation to happen, in your spring SecurityFilter configuration permit all request received for the websocket's destination, and authorize using a ChannelInterceptor.
Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405333 for a detailed example.